# Invalid header error in HTTP SOAP java request

Tags: java, web-services, http, soap

I'm trying to connect to this Web Service ([CDYNE DelayedStockQuote](http://ws.cdyne.com/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx?op=GetQuickQuote)) to draw stock market data through a Java program.

They have a sample SOAP request on that page which I believe I am replicating correctly in my code.

Here is my code:

```
    package stock;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Stock {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
            + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
            + "  <soap:Body>"
            + "    <GetQuickQuote xmlns=\"http://ws.cdyne.com/\">"
            + "      <StockSymbol>GOOG</StockSymbol>"
            + "      <LicenseKey>0</LicenseKey>"
            + "    </GetQuickQuote>"
            + "  </soap:Body>"
            + "</soap:Envelope>";

    String hostname = "ws.cdyne.com";
    int port = 80;
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
    System.out.println(addr);
    Socket sock = new Socket(addr, port);

    //Send header
    String path = "/delayedstockquote/delayedstockquote.asmx";
    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    // You can use "UTF8" for compatibility with the Microsoft virtual machine.
    wr.write("POST " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    wr.write("Host: ws.cdyne.com\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n");
    wr.write("Content-Length: " + XML.length() + "\r\n");
    wr.write("SOAPAction: \"http://ws.cdyne.com/GetQuickQuote\"");
    wr.write("\r\n");

    //Send data
    wr.write(XML);
    wr.flush();

    // Response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    }
}
```

Right now I just have "GOOG" (Google stock symbol) hardcoded into the program as well as a "0" for a license key.

However, when I run this code I get back this error:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server:Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 17:51:46 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length 339

And this message in the XML data:
Bad Request - Invalid Header
HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

Can anyone see a flaw in my code?  One thing that worries me is the fact that the API might be shut down. After doing some research I found this link:
[It says that PowerQuote has been disabled](http://cdyne.com/products/power-quote.aspx)

I'm worried this is why my request isn't working. But I don't know why the first link I provided would send back correct/up-to-date stock information

Any ideas?

EDIT:
As I mentioned in my comment, I got rid of the bad header error by adding in a blank line between my SOAP header and the XML string.  However now I'm just getting a SOAP response header in return with the values:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:  ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 07 Feb 2014 19:14:13 GMT
Content-Length: 372
```

What does this mean?!?!

Comment: Well I got rid of the bad header error. The problem was there was no space between my header and the XML string I was sending. This was resolved by just adding another "wr.write("\r\n");". However, the response I get doesn't give me any meaningful data. I just get an HTTP/1.1 200 OK, Cache-Control: no-cache, Pragma: no-cache....No idea why it isn't returning the data!